# Add page numbers when printing from Microsoft Document Imaging

Tags: microsoft-office

I have to pull many reports from many different pieces of software and combine them all into one format. Every one of these programs outputs an MDI file, which is Microsoft Document Imaging.

Is there a way to add page numbers when printing from Microsoft Document Imaging?